# DownloadFile method in Sharpbox and 403 error

Tags: c#, dropbox, sharpbox

I'm trying to make an application using Sharpbox for download one file of my dropbox directory.
I try to download the file with the downloadFile() method, the code is:

```
    CloudStorage dropBoxStorage = new CloudStorage();
    dropBoxStorage.Open(dropBoxConfig, accessToken); 
    dropBoxStorage.DownloadFile(FilePath, TargetPath);
```

I think that dropBoxConfig and accessToken are fine because I can display the folders and files in dropbox, but when I try to download, I obtain this error:

```
The remote server returned an error (403) forbidden 
Error en el servidor remoto: (403) Prohibido.
```

Help me, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same error response when trying to download a file using `DownloadFile`. Browsing the folder hierarchy or uploading files was working fine. After I found [this issue on the sharpbox bug tracker](http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/workitem/19454) **I changed my .NET C# console application from framework version 4.5 to 4.0 and all of a sudden it worked.**

So this tells me that sharpbox v1.2.0.542 (via NuGet) is not very stable and you might want to use another C# wrapper or write one yourself using the DropBox API directly.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution worked perfectly. Yes, Sharpbox has long time not been updated.